# Groupwise-max on count() with nested subqueries

Tags: mysql

My head is turning to mush when trying to get this nesting around my head.

So basically I got 2 tables:

Brokers, which is my "user" table:

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦
║ ID       ║ EMAIL      ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬
║        1 ║ 1@email.co ║
║        2 ║ 2@email.co ║
║        3 ║ 3@email.co ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

Houses, which is houses that the users have added. Currently user and house is connected by the email column (I know, makes more sense to do with a ID):

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦════════════╦
║ ID       ║ TYPE       ║ EMAIL      ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬════════════╬
║        1 ║ 1          ║ 1@email.co ║
║        2 ║ 3          ║ 1@email.co ║
║        3 ║ 2          ║ 1@email.co ║
║        4 ║ 3          ║ 1@email.co ║
║        5 ║ 3          ║ 1@email.co ║
║        6 ║ 2          ║ 1@email.co ║
║        7 ║ 3          ║ 1@email.co ║
║        8 ║ 1          ║ 2@email.co ║
║        9 ║ 1          ║ 2@email.co ║
║       10 ║ 2          ║ 2@email.co ║
║       11 ║ 2          ║ 2@email.co ║
║       12 ║ 3          ║ 2@email.co ║
║       13 ║ 3          ║ 3@email.co ║
║       14 ║ 2          ║ 3@email.co ║
║       15 ║ 3          ║ 3@email.co ║
║       16 ║ 1          ║ 3@email.co ║
║       17 ║ 3          ║ 3@email.co ║
║       18 ║ 2          ║ 3@email.co ║
║       19 ║ 2          ║ 3@email.co ║
║       20 ║ 3          ║ 3@email.co ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Now what I want to do, is that I want to select all brokers that have type 3 as the highest, most popular kind of house added. So for example if house type 3 represents "Apartments", I want to find the brokers that sell apartments as their number one most popular type.

My current query is:

```
SELECT b.id, b.email, h.email, h.type, h.total
FROM brokers b
INNER JOIN (
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total, email, type
FROM house
GROUP BY email, type
ORDER BY total DESC
)h ON b.email = h.email
AND h.type =  "3"
ORDER BY b.id DESC
```

Now this only selects the total amount of houses that that broker has for type 3. It does not only select the brokers where type 3 is their most popular type.

Now to do that, I need to use what is called "Groupwise Max". But I can not use max() on a count(*) like:

```
MAX(COUNT(*)) as max_value
```

So I guess that what I need to do is to nest my query further with additional subqueries to first count, and then select the max value.

I've been trying to get it right for a while now and I just can't get my head around it. Anyone can help?

EDIT:
Expected Output:
Based on the table above, Broker 1@email.co got:

- 1 House with Type 1.
- 2 Houses with Type 2.
- 4 Houses with Type 3.

Broker 2@email.co got:

- 2 houses with Type 1
- 2 houses with Type 2
- 1 house with Type 3.

Broker 3@email.co got:

- 1 house with Type 1.
- 3 houses with Type 2.
- 4 houses with Type 3.

Since both 1@email.co and 3@email.co is selling House Type 3 most commonly, they should be included in the output. 2@email.co do not sell type 3 as his most popular type, so he should not be included in the result.

So output:

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦════════════╦
║ ID       ║ EMAIL      ║ Total      ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬════════════╬
║        1 ║ 1@email.co ║ 4          ║
║        3 ║ 3@email.co ║ 4          ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝════════════╝
```

Comment: Can you please share sample data with expected output?

Comment: Added additional sample data and expected output and explination.

Answer (score -1):

I can't understand why you need Count()? I think, according to you question ("select all brokers that have type 3") , it doesn't make sense, or do I misunderstand something?

**EDIT:**
I have done it in SQL SERVER by temporary table and variable
If you can convert it to mysql syntax, your problem will we solved:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, Email, [Type]
into #tbl3
from house
group by Email, Type

declare @a int
set @a = (select MAX(total) from #tbl3)

SELECT b.id, b.email, h.email, h.type, h.total
FROM brokers b
inner join
(
select * from #tbl3
where total=@a
) h
on h.Email=b.Email and h.Type=3
```

**EDIT:** This is MySql syntax which will do your job.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS (
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, Email, Type
from house
group by Email, Type
);

set @a = (select MAX(total) from table2);

SELECT b.id, b.email, h.email, h.type, h.total
FROM brokers b
inner join
(
select * from table2
where total=@a
) h
on h.Email=b.Email and h.Type=3
```

Comment: I need to cound the houses and group them by type, to know what house-type that is most popular for that broker. If I dont count them, I can not know which is the "most common type" for that broker.

Comment: @Marcus Lind, didn't my answer help you?? it's annoying to see a working example with a downvote

Answer (score -1):

Posting answer without executing, hope this works!

```
Select a.ID,a.Email,b.Cnt from Brokers as a
inner join (
            Select Email,count(ID) as Cnt from Houses where Type =
                  (Select max(Type) from Houses) 
             group by Email
           ) as b on a.Email = b.Email
```

Comment: This does not check if type 3 is the "most popular" or "maximum value" of the types of houses that the broker has added. This will return all brokers no matter if type 3 is their least common type of house, or most common.